# How to use expo expo-file-system uploadAsync with asset from expo-media-library getAssetsAsync

Tags: react-native, expo, assets, media-library

**getAssetsAsync** returns list of assets where uri look like:

`"ph://ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED"`

I trying to call **uploadAsync**
`const upload = await uploadAsync('http://localhost:8181/api/upload', post.image.uri);`

But I receive error:

`ExceptionsManager.js:180 Unhandled promise rejection Error: Cannot upload file 'ph://ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED'. Only 'file://' URI are supported.`

How can I fix it?